# How to write JSON object to an existing JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file that I want to update whenever user wants to add a new Object to the file. I am using plain HTML and javascript and jquery.
Is there a javascript/jquery function/ method that will allow me to be able to append a new JSON object in the external json file?

Below is the structure of my JSON file.

```js
[{
  "Links": [{
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "Name": "Google"
  }],
  "Name": "Google Page"
}, {
  "Links": [{
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
    "Name": "Facebook"
  }],
  "Name": "Facebook Page"
}]
```

Comment: From my limited understanding, it is not possible to write to files on the file system through your browser environment. You may need to write an API layer in NodeJS or something similar to help you do this

Comment: Not really, no, as the file will be held server-side where JS cannot reach it. Also note that writing to a physical JSON file will not scale at all. A much better solution would be to update a database and then generate the JSON file from that when needed.

Comment: Actually using only client side Javascript you can not write it to a file. For that you have to use any other server side language. Due to security reason it is not allowed from browser JS to access client's file system.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You would need to read the file, parse the JSON, edit the data structure, serialize back to JSON, then save the file.

JavaScript has no built-in mechanisms for reading or writing files, it depends on the host environment to provide them.

Since you tagged this [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), it seems likely you want to do this in a browser. Browsers have an API for reading files, but not for writing them. You'll need to use HTTP and write server-side code to handle writing to the file instead.

You'd probably be best off not using JSON as a storage format (it is great as a transport format), and to run a real database on your server and generate JSON from it on demand.

Comment: Yes I need to do this in a browser. How can i achieve this?
Any sample code will be very helpful. I am newbie to this.

Comment: @user2240189 — I explained the steps in the answer. Deal with each one in turn. Ask a more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: using below piece of code i have added a new object to the array
$.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
   
   
   var newObj = {Name: 'Test'} 
   
   data.push(newObj);   
     
  });
Now how can i write back to the existing json file

Comment: Step 1: Pick a server-side language. Step 2: Write a web service for writing to the file in it